# Ubuntu Server HTTP redirect to other server?

Tags: networking, server

OK, so I have two servers on my local network. One of them serves CCTV over the internet (for remote viewing) and the other serves Wordpress sites. The CCTV server is in my router's DMZ, but since I can only assign one machine to the DMZ, I am wondering if there's a way I can keep the existing CCTV stream but also redirect to the other server, perhaps using some kind of port forwarding.
Alas, I don't yet have a good enough understanding of Terminal commands to accomplish this.

Both machines run Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS and have static IP addresses on the LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, your both machines are behind a router, but first is in the DMZ, and you want to open the second one to the web too?

If that is the case, you can use port forwarding option of your router and forward external port (8080 for example) to internal port (IP of the machine, port 8080).

Also, if you added first one to DMZ just for the sake of one port, you should remove it from DMZ and just forward the one that you need.